# Python flask wtforms read image from canvas dataurl instead of form.input.data

Tags: javascript, python, canvas, flask, wtforms

I have currently a working JS code to resize images clientside. Now I need to send this resized image to my flask app. My flask app will then upload it to aws3.

This is the JS code which I use to resize the image, it also generates a dataurl:

```
$( "input[type='file']" ).change(function() {

    // from an input element
    var filesToUpload = this.files;
    console.log(filesToUpload);

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

    $( img ).load(function() {

        var MAX_WIDTH = 600;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 450;
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
          if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
          }
        } else {
          if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
          }
        }       

        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

        var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        //var file = canvas.mozGetAsFile("foo.png");

    });

});
```

In my flask app I used `form.company_logo_image_path.data.read()` to get the filecontents, but now even if I resize the resized image is ignored. That is because I am still getting the old image from the input. I need to get the canvas image.

How do I use the dataurl to get the image in my flask app?
Or is there an other way?

That is my AJAX code which I use right after I get the dataurl:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/profil/unternehmen-bearbeiten",
  data:{
    imageBase64: dataurl
  }
}).done(function() {
  console.log('sent');
});
```

In my python view I try to access the dataurl:

```
data_url = request.values['imageBase64']
#data_url = request.args.get('image')   # here parse the data_url out http://xxxxx/?image={dataURL}
print data_url
content = data_url.split(';')[1]
image_encoded = content.split(',')[1]
body = base64.decodebytes(image_encoded.encode('utf-8'))
# Then do whatever you want
print body, type(body)
```

Answer (score 2):

per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL, you get something like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(dataURL);
// "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNby
// blAAAADElEQVQImWNgoBMAAABpAAFEI8ARAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
```

Then just use base64 decode the file out.

```
import base64
from flask import request

def your_view():
    data_url = request.args.get('image')   # here parse the data_url out http://xxxxx/?image={dataURL}
    content = data_url.split(';')[1]
    image_encoded = content.split(',')[1]
    body = base64.decodebytes(image_encoded.encode('utf-8'))
    # Then do whatever you want
```

body is what you need.

Comment: I know. I already saw the dataURL output in the console, it worked fine. But how do I access this in my flask app?

Comment: I could create a seperate view and method which decodes the dataurl, but I do not know how to pass the dataURL to mentioned method.

Comment: @Roman How to pass it to view depends on you, you create a new view listening on an endpoint, e.g http://xxxx/images, then in js, append the dataURL you get to the query string of the endpoint, e.g http://xxxx/images?image={dataURL}, then send the request with $.get

Comment: I understand the theory but I still have no clue how to get the dataurl into my python... data_url = request.args.get('image') gives me bad request 400 or it is None and all other tries result in the same error

Comment: Google search flask get request query string.

Comment: I used your idea to get the image and managed to do so, but I am facing now other issues, here is my progress and new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783686/python-flask-request-dataurl-from-url-for-decoding-base64-image

Comment: your code didnt worked in this state, I will edit it if I manage to solve the problem completely and will accept it.